# Bulk.insert Spring Mongo API: Is there a limit to the number of documents i can perform a bulk insert for

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, bulkinsert, bson, spring-mongo

Recently, I was trying to perform a bulk insert using the bulk.insert (List) API. However, I got an exception saying that payload document size has exceeded the maximum size of 16MB. As far as I know, every document was well below 16MB. Does this mean that the 16MB limit applies to the ENTIRE list of documents I pass to the API? I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Drivers generally enforce a 16m limit on commands. There is some leeway for command overhead to allow inserting a document that is 16m in size (in which case the command sent by the driver to the database would exceed 16m). This overhead allowance should be about 16k.

Although I personally haven't tested it, it seems that the server allows command documents up to 48m in size which permits a command to, for example, perform a find-and-modify operation where the query is 16m (such as providing 16m of data and asking the database to match document content exactly to that) and the update command provides 16m of new data for the document, plus command overhead.

When performing bulk writes, the driver is generally supposed to split the writes such that each write is under 16m+16k limit. This is specified [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/driver-bulk-update.rst#request-size-limits). If your driver doesn't split bulk writes at all or splits them incorrectly this may be an issue to report to the driver.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! On receiving your reply, I took to examining every document carefully, and found that one of them indeed, exceeded the 16MB document size limit. In this case, the splitting of bulk writes wouldn't have helped. Thanks again for providing a reference to the relevant documentation